# Jquery horizontal slide based on div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jquery script where you can click a left and right button and it will scroll horizontally to show more content.

The content that needs to be scrolled are in a div with a width of 1296px, but i want to set my jquery code to automatically get the width of the div and when you press on one of the left or right scroll button it will scroll exactly 1296px.

I want to do it this way because I need to later on optimize the design for all screen size and this would be the easier way.

My code:

```
    var $item2 = $('div.group'), //Cache your DOM selector
    visible2 = 1, //Set the number of items that will be visible
    index2 = 0, //Starting index
    endIndex2 = ( $item.length ); //End index

$('#arrowR').click(function(){
      index2++;
      $item2.animate({'left':'-=1296px'});
});

$('#arrowL').click(function(){
    if(index2 > 0){
      index2--;            
      $item2.animate({'left':'+=18.5%'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please add some of the HTML that this is being executed on...it makes it easier to troubleshoot. Thanks.

Comment: This is the html: http://pastebin.com/dbCLPDXm and this is the css: http://pastebin.com/gxSARjJc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Javascript should work:

```
    var $item2 = $('div.group'), //Cache your DOM selector
    visible2 = 1, //Set the number of items that will be visible
    index2 = 0, //Starting index
    endIndex2 = ( $item2.length ); //End index
    var w = $("#group").width();

$('#arrowR').click(function(){
      index2++;
      $item2.animate({'left':'-=' + w + 'px'});
});

$('#arrowL').click(function(){
    if(index2 > 0){
      index2--;            
      $item2.animate({'left':'+=' + w + 'px'});
    }
});
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5fy0h8e/). Basically we calculate the width initially to not do the same thing repeatedly and the reuse it whenever we need it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the width of the visible container first, and then use that value later? Quick example:

```
var width = $('container').width();
```

And then during animations:

```
var left = $item2.css('left') + width;
$item.animate({'left',left});
```

As a note, [`innerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/) and [`outerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) may be more beneficial than just [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) depending on how you've set everything up, so if values aren't quite right take a look at those documents.

Comment: Hmm, I've did what you said, but when it's not doing anything http://pastebin.com/Aqv19e97

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fiddle that I think solves your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/77bvnw3n/

What I did was to create another variable (called `width`) which on page load, dynamically gets the width of the container.

```
var width = $('.group-container').width(); //Container Width
```

This variable is also reset whenever the Next or Previous buttons are pressed (in case the window has been resized since the page loaded).

```
 $('#arrowR').click(function(){
   index2++;

   //recheck container width
   width = $('.group-container').width();

   $item2.animate({'left':'-=' + width + 'px'});
});
```

Take a look and let me know if it helps.

**Note**: I replaced the 'Next' and 'Previous' images with coloured boxes in my Fiddle and I think you also had a typo in your code, should

```
endIndex2 = ( $item.length )
```

be changed to:

```
endIndex2 = ( $item2.length )
```